# Access list of Dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary items and I want to access them in Javascript. How can I do this?
It is an ajax result and result.d gives the list. (ListItem1, ListItem2, ListItem3)
If I use result.ListItem1[0] I get the value. How can I access the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response. I used the following to access the Key of the dictionary:

```
for (t in result.ListItem1) 
{
    type = result.ListItem1[t];
    typeId = t;
    alert(t);
    o.push('<option value="');
    o.push(t);
    o.push('" class="chz-option">');
    o.push(type);
    o.push('</option>');
}
$('#type').html(o.join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

`result.ListItem1[0].key` or `result.ListItem1[0]['key']`

Replace "key" with whatever key you are actually wanting to access.

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate all the properties of your object

```js
var prop, result = {
  d: {
    ListItem1: ['value1'],
    ListItem2: ['value2'],
    ListItem3: ['value3']
  }
};

for (prop in result.d) {
  if (result.d.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(result.d[prop]);
  }
}
```

In the log you would then see the 3 array values